# Manual pagination in Room

Tags: android, sqlite, pagination, android-room

I am wondering about different ways of implementing manual SQLite pagination using Room. I am absolutely not willing to use Paging library as its implementation is way too concrete.

Currently I am using the `LIMIT` approach with an implicit `offset` of 0 because I want to receive table updates for all pages loaded so far, using `Flow`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TaskEntity ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT :limit
```

But this kinda defeats the purpose of pagination since for page `N` with page size `S` I am querying not `S` rows, but `S(N + 1)` rows. I don't even see a way to use the seek method since I want to listen for updates.

My question is, if it is possible to implement pagination query which complexity only depends on `S`, and simultaneously listen to rows from 0 up to `S(N + 1)`, how do I do that, and if not, at what scale am I to expect performance problems using my current approach?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following could be the **basis** (***Note** there are 3 sections throughout the answer. The first the Query, the second A demo using Room and finally some timings (re **performance** on an AS emulator (performance will be impacted by the device, so impossible to give anything other than a `looks like it may be ok`, answer))*):-

```
/* STEP 3 - get rows (all for brevity and simplicity of the demo) with the page number for 10 pagesize */
WITH
    pagesize(ps) AS (SELECT 10 /* The size of a page which could be passed e.g. (SELECT :pageSize) */),
    cte_paged(x,page,createdAt,blah) AS (
        SELECT -1,0,-1,'' 
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT
                 x+1,
                (x+1) / (SELECT ps FROM pagesize),
                (SELECT taskentity.createdAt FROM taskentity WHERE taskentity.createdAt > cte_paged.createdAt LIMIT 1),
                'xxx' /* Blah */ 
            FROM cte_paged LIMIT (SELECT count(*) FROM taskentity)
    )
SELECT *,datetime(createdat,'unixepoch') /* column added just to make demo easier */ AS easyread FROM cte_paged WHERE x > -1;
```

- WHERE pagesize is the size of a page.

As from the demo explained below for a pagesize of 10 then this could be the output (which could be easily be a single page if the final WHERE clause were amended accordingly).

[image]

- As can be seen 10 rows per page

**How is this works**

It uses CTE's (common table expressions (likes temporary tables but they only exist for the duration of the execution)).

The **pagesize** cte will be a single row with a single column **ps** simply to enable the pagesize to be passed and used.

The cte_paged is a recursive cte. It has 4 columns:-

- x a counter that increments by 1 for each row (not really required but perhaps easier to understand)
- page similar BUT the divided by the pages so the page that a particular row resides in.
- createdAt will as be the taskEntity's createdAt for the row
- blah wil be as per the taskEntity's blah column (blah representing other columns)
- The recursion is due to the UNION ALL effectively with itself, it will be never ending without a means of ending and hence the LIMIT (a WHERE clause not being met also satisfies the end of the loop)

The SELECT is what is to be done with the **WITH**.

- **see demo for example(s)**

**Demo**

The following demonstrates the above in 3 steps/stages (4 if you consider the cleanup). The **first stage** loads some data, 1000 rows, with the createdAt column being the current date time and then less 1 hour for each subsequent row. Note that this also uses a recursive CTE **WITH** it **INSERT**ing data. Each the the other **stage**s extracts data according to the page size passed (hard coded as an SQLite Tool has been used to demonstrate).

**Stage/Step 1** setting up some testing data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS taskentity; /* just in case */
/* Stage 1 Create the core data to be tested */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS taskentity (createdat INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, blah TEXT);
/* Use a recursive CTE to load some data (1000 rows) with createdAt being the current datetime less 1 hour*/
WITH
    cte(x) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cte LIMIT 1000)
INSERT INTO taskentity SELECT strftime('%s','now','-'||(x+1)||' hours'),'blah'||(x+1) FROM cte;
SELECT * FROM taskentity; /* output the core data that has been created */
```

***Results in**:-

[image]

- note that blah1001 was in fact the last row inserted but the first displayed as the only available index was on the createdAt column and the default sort is **ASC**ending. So the earliest createdAt (now less 1000 hours) appears first.

  - In real life, if order is important then ORDER BY should be used, you should never try to rely on what you think the query optimiser will do.

**Stage/Step 2** first example

```
/* STEP 2 - get rows (all for brevity and simplicity of the demo) with the page number for 256 pagesize */
WITH
    pagesize(ps) AS (SELECT 256),
    cte_paged(x,page,createdAt,blah) AS (
        SELECT -1,0,-1,'' 
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT
                 x+1,
                (x+1) / (SELECT ps FROM pagesize),
                (SELECT taskentity.createdAt FROM taskentity WHERE taskentity.createdAt > cte_paged.createdAt LIMIT 1),
                (SELECT taskentity.blah FROM taskentity WHERE taskentity.createdAt > cte_paged.createdAt LIMIT 1)
            FROM cte_paged LIMIT (SELECT count(*) FROM taskentity)
    )
SELECT *,datetime(createdat,'unixepoch') AS easyread FROM cte_paged WHERE createdAt >= 0;
```

For this example the number of rows per page is to be 256 (see the pagesize CTE). The result includes:-

[image]

- x column is effectively the number of the row
- page is the page the row belongs to page 0 for the first 256 rows (0-255), 1 257-511 inclusive and so on.

**Stage/Step 3** 10 per page (as initially shown both the code and the results)

**Stage/Step 4** cleanup
/* Cleanup the demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS taskentity;

Adapting for use in Room. Basically the entire SQL is coded in the `@Query` parameter.  See the comment in the initial code for example of passing the pagesize as a parameter.

- obviously the names of cte's can be changed to suit.
- the demo code may not be the most efficient, it has been written with the hope that it is relatively easy to get an idea of what is happening.

---

**Room Demo**

---

To demonstrate the above using Room then consider the following code:-

**TaskEntity** (Entity):-

```
@Entity(tableName = "taskentity")
data class TaskEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    var createdAt: Long=System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000,
    val blah: String
)
```

**AllDAOs** `@Dao` annotated interface :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(task: TaskEntity): Long
    @Query("SELECT count(*) / :pageSize FROM taskentity;")
    fun getHighestPage(pageSize: Int): Int
    @Query("WITH" +
            "   pagesize(ps) AS (SELECT :pageSize)," +
            "   cte_paged(x,page,createdAt,blah) AS (" +
            "       SELECT -1,0,-1,'' " +
            "       UNION ALL " +
            "           SELECT" +
            "                x+1," +
            "               (x+1) / (SELECT ps FROM pagesize)," +
            "               (SELECT taskentity.createdAt FROM taskentity WHERE taskentity.createdAt > cte_paged.createdAt LIMIT 1)," +
            "               (SELECT taskentity.blah FROM taskentity WHERE taskentity.createdAt > cte_paged.createdAt LIMIT 1)" +
            "           FROM cte_paged LIMIT (SELECT count(*) FROM taskentity)" +
            "   )" +
            /* WHERE clause includes parameter to get a specific page */
            "SELECT *,datetime(createdat,'unixepoch') AS easyread FROM cte_paged WHERE createdAt >= 0 AND page=:pageToGet;")
    fun getAPage(pageSize: Int, pageToGet: Int): List<TaskEntity>
}
```

1. `insert` function
2. `getHighestPage` to return Int with the highest page according to the specified page size (note assumes **ALL** rows, so may need to be adjusted if extracting a subset)
3. The CTE as per the answer. NOTE literally copied and pasted from the SQLite Tool (Navicat) and the line feeds removed and then the following changes:-

   1. `256` (hard coded value) changed to `:pageSize` so passed as a paremter.
   2. `AND page=:pageToGet` added to the WHERE clause of the SELECT query that is derived from the **WITH** (so a single page of data is extracted).

**TheDatabase** (suitable **FOR THE DEMO** `@Database` annotated abstract class) :-

```
@Database(entities = [TaskEntity::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity** code to actually do something (see comments):-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        /* Get DB and Dao */
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()
        /* Load some testing data (1000 rows with createdAt now and then now + 1 hour (oops should have been -1 hour but ....)) */
        buildSomeData(1000)
        /* Do some extracts (or not for invalid page (2nd call)) */
        logStuff(10,3)
        logStuff(10,999)
        logStuff(35,27)
    }

    /* Function to add some data # of rows as passed */
    fun buildSomeData(number_of_rows: Int) {
        val onehour = 60 * 60;
        val baseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
        for(i in 0.. number_of_rows) {
            dao.insert(TaskEntity(baseTime + (i * onehour),"blah${i}"))
        }
    }

    /* Use the 2 @Queries with pagesize and pageToGet as passed to the function */
    fun logStuff(pageSize: Int, pageToGet: Int) {
        val highestPage = dao.getHighestPage(pageSize)
        Log.d("DBINFO","Highest Page when pagesize is ${pageSize} is ${highestPage}")
        /* Can the page be retrieved ????? */
        if (pageToGet > highestPage) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","OOOOPS page # ${pageToGet} is greater than the highest page, whihc is ${highestPage}")
            return
        }
        /* Appears that the page can be retrieved so get it */
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (r in dao.getAPage(pageSize,pageToGet)) {
            sb.append("\n\tBLAH is ${r.blah} CREATED AT is ${r.createdAt}")
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO","Page ${pageToGet} is comprised of ${sb.toString()}")
    }
}
```

**Results of the Demo** :-

```
2023-09-22 13:49:50.614 D/DBINFO: Highest Page when pagesize is 10 is 100
2023-09-22 13:49:50.618 D/DBINFO: Page 3 is comprised of 
        BLAH is blah30 CREATED AT is 1695462588
        BLAH is blah31 CREATED AT is 1695466188
        BLAH is blah32 CREATED AT is 1695469788
        BLAH is blah33 CREATED AT is 1695473388
        BLAH is blah34 CREATED AT is 1695476988
        BLAH is blah35 CREATED AT is 1695480588
        BLAH is blah36 CREATED AT is 1695484188
        BLAH is blah37 CREATED AT is 1695487788
        BLAH is blah38 CREATED AT is 1695491388
        BLAH is blah39 CREATED AT is 1695494988
2023-09-22 13:49:50.618 D/DBINFO: Highest Page when pagesize is 10 is 100
2023-09-22 13:49:50.618 D/DBINFO: OOOOPS page # 999 is greater than the highest page, whihc is 100
2023-09-22 13:49:50.619 D/DBINFO: Highest Page when pagesize is 35 is 28
2023-09-22 13:49:50.622 D/DBINFO: Page 27 is comprised of 
        BLAH is blah945 CREATED AT is 1698756588
        BLAH is blah946 CREATED AT is 1698760188
        BLAH is blah947 CREATED AT is 1698763788
        BLAH is blah948 CREATED AT is 1698767388
        BLAH is blah949 CREATED AT is 1698770988
        BLAH is blah950 CREATED AT is 1698774588
        BLAH is blah951 CREATED AT is 1698778188
        BLAH is blah952 CREATED AT is 1698781788
        BLAH is blah953 CREATED AT is 1698785388
        BLAH is blah954 CREATED AT is 1698788988
        BLAH is blah955 CREATED AT is 1698792588
        BLAH is blah956 CREATED AT is 1698796188
        BLAH is blah957 CREATED AT is 1698799788
        BLAH is blah958 CREATED AT is 1698803388
        BLAH is blah959 CREATED AT is 1698806988
        BLAH is blah960 CREATED AT is 1698810588
        BLAH is blah961 CREATED AT is 1698814188
        BLAH is blah962 CREATED AT is 1698817788
        BLAH is blah963 CREATED AT is 1698821388
        BLAH is blah964 CREATED AT is 1698824988
        BLAH is blah965 CREATED AT is 1698828588
        BLAH is blah966 CREATED AT is 1698832188
        BLAH is blah967 CREATED AT is 1698835788
        BLAH is blah968 CREATED AT is 1698839388
        BLAH is blah969 CREATED AT is 1698842988
        BLAH is blah970 CREATED AT is 1698846588
        BLAH is blah971 CREATED AT is 1698850188
        BLAH is blah972 CREATED AT is 1698853788
        BLAH is blah973 CREATED AT is 1698857388
        BLAH is blah974 CREATED AT is 1698860988
        BLAH is blah975 CREATED AT is 1698864588
        BLAH is blah976 CREATED AT is 1698868188
        BLAH is blah977 CREATED AT is 1698871788
        BLAH is blah978 CREATED AT is 1698875388
        BLAH is blah979 CREATED AT is 1698878988
```

- **NOTE the above, as previously stated, is the BASIS or IN-PRINCIPLE code and as such it is expected that the answer is adapted to suit. Furthermore, the assumption is that the any Android Version is the target and thus potentially more efficient methods, available to higher Android API's only, have not been utilised.**

---

> **how do I do that, and if not, at what scale am I to expect performance problems using my current approach?**

---

Adjusted the above to load 1000000 rows and with logging to ascertain timings, Resulting in (noting that the load were all individual transactions, aka not at all optimised):-

Actually stopped the App after something like 30 minutes, changed to add 1000 rows and reran (just over 0.5 million rows).

The log (with some additional logging added) shows:-

```
2023-09-22 14:40:49.810 D/DBINFO: Initiating LOAD of Data
2023-09-22 14:40:51.457 D/DBINFO: Data now loaded. Initiating extracts (1,2 and then 3)
```

- So nearly 2 seconds to load 1000 rows BUT

:-

```
2023-09-22 14:40:51.466 D/DBINFO: Highest Page when pagesize is 10 is 5079
2023-09-22 14:40:51.572 D/DBINFO: Page 3 is comprised of 
        BLAH is blah10 CREATED AT is 1695390588
        BLAH is blah10 CREATED AT is 1695392377
        BLAH is blah10 CREATED AT is 1695393649
        BLAH is blah11 CREATED AT is 1695394188
        BLAH is blah11 CREATED AT is 1695395977
        BLAH is blah11 CREATED AT is 1695397249
        BLAH is blah12 CREATED AT is 1695397788
        BLAH is blah12 CREATED AT is 1695399577
        BLAH is blah12 CREATED AT is 1695400849
        BLAH is blah13 CREATED AT is 1695401388
2023-09-22 14:40:51.572 D/DBINFO: ALL done with Extract 1
2023-09-22 14:40:51.575 D/DBINFO: Highest Page when pagesize is 10 is then 5079 pages
2023-09-22 14:40:51.576 D/DBINFO: OOOOPS page # 99999999 is greater than the highest page, whihc is 5079
2023-09-22 14:40:51.576 D/DBINFO: All done with Extract 2
2023-09-22 14:40:51.579 D/DBINFO: Highest Page when pagesize is 35 is 1451
2023-09-22 14:40:51.687 D/DBINFO: Page 27 is comprised of 
        BLAH is blah315 CREATED AT is 1696488588
        BLAH is blah315 CREATED AT is 1696490377
        BLAH is blah315 CREATED AT is 1696491649
        BLAH is blah316 CREATED AT is 1696492188
        ....
```

- 1/10th second to run the 3 extracts (against the entire 0.5 million rows)
- when pagesize = 10 then 50790ish rows, when pagesize is 35 then 50785ish rows ( App Inspection shows 50795).